# how to disable middleware in specific page, nuxt middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, middleware, nuxt-auth

### i have declare a middleware that check role of every routes in nuxt.config.js. but want to disable in some pages.

```
// in nuxt.config.js =>        
        router: {
            middleware: ['role']
          },
        
        
        
 // in middleware/role.js =>     
        export default function ({app}) {
          if (!window.localStorage.getItem('auth.token')) {    
            //app.router.push('/auth/login');   
            console.log('middleware');
          }
        }
        
        
 // in login.vue =>     
            export default {
                role: false,
              }
    
    
 // in root page =>
        export default { 
          role: false,               
          middleware({app}){
            if (!window.localStorage.getItem('auth.token')) {
              app.router.push('/auth/login');
            }
          },    
      }
```

when token is empty and redirect user, the page is loading again and again so i comment this redirect and console log a message, to check what happen.
this role middleware is loading on that page where the role middleware is set to false.
check the image below.

[image: image of browser console]

here you can see middleware printed twice, one for root('/') and another one for login page (here i disabled role middleware). how to disable this middleware to this login page.

Comment: you can check route.path in middleware and return if this variable equal your path.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```js
middleware({ route }) {
  if (!['do-not-run-here', 'public-page', 'index'].includes(route.name)) return

  // all your cool code here
  console.log('passed')
},
```

You can have some quick return in case this is a page you don't want to have a middleware. In my example, we do check the name of the route, and if it's `do-no-run-here`, `public-page` or `index` the middleware is simply not executed there.
Of course, setting a `name` prop is good if you want to be sure of the name of the page.

On all the other ones, the middleware will run perfectly fine. There is no `middleware: false` if it's what you were looking for.

---

An alternative solution would be to use a specific `layout` for some pages, with the middleware on it. And not use this one for the pages you don't want to have the middleware on.

Comment: can u please explain more or use example code.. we should use your code in nuxt config or in specific page that this guy mention it ?

Comment: @ArianFm the snippet of code can be used where you want. It could be a `.vue` page, could be a global middleware, "classic" middleware that you use per component. I didn't make it more specific because it's depends of your use case.

Comment: im using nuxt auth and my middleware looks like this (in nuxt.config.js): router:{
    middleware:['auth']
  },

Comment: @ArianFm if you're trying to disable the nuxt auth middleware in specific pages, you can use the following: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware Also, feel free to open a new question. I'm not sure this is the exact same question OP asked here.

Comment: youre amazing thanks for your guide , i cant believe didnt see that part of middleware document :D

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sourav and Kissu, this thread helped me accomplish something similar in my Nuxt 3 project. I used a variation of your idea to exclude routes on server middleware.

May it help a future adventurer who finds their way to this place

```
// ~/server/middleware/auth.ts

import type { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";
// other imports

export default async (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
  const reqUrl = req.url;

  /**
   * Public Endpoints
   *
   * /api/ routes explicitly excluded from this auth middleware
   */

  if (req.url.includes("api/example")) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can filter page in Nuxt 3 global middleware

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(
  (to, from) => {
    // you can use params to & from of middleware to check like this
    if (['demo'].includes(to.name as string)) {
      return // here this middleware will not execute anything with specific routes in the array.
    }
  })
```

Hope this help.