# Middleware is running even set to false

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I created a folder middleware and a file called auth.js.

[image]

`auth.js`

```js
export default function auth() {
  console.log('auth!')
}
```

And in `nuxt.config.js` I'm calling it in *router* object.

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['auth']
},
```

And every page that I enter I see the console.log I put in Auth.js. And what I'm trying to do is to avoid the middleware to run in Login page, but even when I set it to false, it runs.

`Login.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="div">LOGIN PAGE!!!</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  auth: false
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you `auth: false` is a confusion that you're making regarding [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware) module.

Here, since you're not using that, you cannot bypass your middleware with `auth: false`, it doesn't have any effect tbh.
If you want to have a conditional middleware in your component, you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68985365/8816585).
Otherwise, you can write something similar in a `/middleware/auth.js` file too.

You could even probably make a similar behavior of checking some `auth` key on the instance yourself (homemade solution).
For an approach on how to do that, check [this article](https://dev.to/michaelthiessen/25-vue-tips-you-need-to-know-2h70) with the point `18. Component Metadata`.