# Change the content in Nuxt.js middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

Is there any way to mutate the content of the response (e.g. page) in the middleware?

I should also mention that I don't want to push a new route (change the URL).

Comment: Could you please be more explicit here? Also, what did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu I have a middleware which checks whether the user has the right permission, and if not, I want to replace the page's content with something else. I don't want to change the entire response (e.g. layout) and only wants to changed `<nuxt />`.

Comment: You could then `$router.push` the user to another page if he doesn't have enough permission. Could be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943001/8816585 Also, official docs are pretty good at explaining this: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware

Comment: @kissu That's the point; I don't want to navigate the user (change the URL).

Comment: Wrap the whole page in an `v-if` checking the role of the user. If the user don't have the permission, show him the `v-else`.

Comment: @kissu yeah that would be a temporary solution but I originally wanted as some kind of middleware which I can reuse for several pages.

Comment: I'm not sure to see how something like this could be clean because it introduces some serious side effects. It probably depends of your template and data but with just this kind of info, it doesn't look like the best practice ever.

Comment: @kissu Yeah. After some research it seems it's not the best idea to mutate the response via middleware. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutating the content of a page in a middleware (in some Express-y way I guess) while staying on the same route is not something that you usually do on the front-end. Never saw it and it's a pretty good anti-pattern IMO.

You can make ugly conditionals by wrapping your whole template tho.

Best way would be to receive a different payload from the backend and adapt to it in your front-end.